# #including a class header does not specify type

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am encountering a very strange problem in my wxWidgets application. What I am trying to do is use a custom wxPanel resource to allow for some redundancy control and providing methods that allow me to work easier. This problem was not occurring before I tried to pass access to a resource in the main frame to each panel.

What I am doing is using #include to include the class header of the wxPanel resource in the header of the main class. However, when trying to declare a resource of the type CopyRow, which is in the header file I am including, I get the error `CopyRow does not name a type`

Here is the code for the main class header,

```
#ifndef CPAMOUNTMAIN_H
#define CPAMOUNTMAIN_H

//(*Headers(CPAmountFrame)
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/spinctrl.h>
#include <wx/statline.h>
#include "CopyRow.h"
#include <wx/panel.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/statusbr.h>
//*)

class CPAmountFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:

        CPAmountFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id = -1);
        void UpdateTotal();
        virtual ~CPAmountFrame();

    private:

        //(*Handlers(CPAmountFrame)
        void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OntotalCopiesChange(wxSpinEvent& event);
        static void CallTotalCopies();
        //*)

        //(*Identifiers(CPAmountFrame)
        static const long ID_CUSTOM1;
        static const long ID_CUSTOM2;
        static const long ID_CUSTOM3;
        static const long ID_CUSTOM4;
        static const long ID_CUSTOM5;
        static const long ID_CUSTOM6;
        static const long ID_STATICLINE1;
        static const long ID_STATICTEXT1;
        static const long ID_SPINCTRL1;
        static const long ID_STATICTEXT2;
        static const long ID_PANEL1;
        static const long idMenuQuit;
        static const long idMenuAbout;
        static const long ID_STATUSBAR1;
        //*)

        //(*Declarations(CPAmountFrame)
        CopyRow* Custom4;
        wxStaticText* totalPrice;
        CopyRow* Custom1;
        CopyRow* Custom5;
        CopyRow* Custom2;
        CopyRow* Custom3;
        wxPanel* Panel1;
        wxStaticText* StaticText1;
        wxStatusBar* StatusBar1;
        wxStaticLine* StaticLine1;
        CopyRow* Custom6;
        wxSpinCtrl* totalCopies;
        //*)

        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

#endif // CPAMOUNTMAIN_H
```

And here is the code for CopyRow.h,

```
#ifndef COPYROW_H
#define COPYROW_H

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    //(*HeadersPCH(CopyRow)
    #include <wx/sizer.h>
    #include <wx/stattext.h>
    #include <wx/panel.h>
    //*)
#endif
//(*Headers(CopyRow)
#include <wx/spinctrl.h>
//*)
#include "CPAmountMain.h"

class CopyRow: public wxPanel
{
    public:

        CopyRow(wxWindow* parent,const char* label,wxSpinCtrl* copies,wxWindowID id=wxID_ANY,const wxPoint& pos=wxDefaultPosition,const wxSize& size=wxDefaultSize);
        void SetLabel(const char* label);
        void SetPrice(double price);
        void SetCounter(int value);
        int  GetCounter();
        virtual ~CopyRow();

    private:

        //(*Declarations(CopyRow)
        wxStaticText* copyLabel;
        wxSpinCtrl* numCopies;
        wxStaticText* copyPrice;
        //*)

        //(*Identifiers(CopyRow)
        static const long ID_SPINCTRL1;
        static const long ID_STATICTEXT1;
        static const long ID_STATICTEXT2;
        //*)

        wxSpinCtrl* totalCopies;

        //(*Handlers(CopyRow)
        void OnnumCopiesChange(wxSpinEvent& event);
        //*)
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

#endif
```

Can anyone explain this error to me? I have no clue right now.

Comment: Is that the only error you get? Are you sure it's in `cpamountmain.h`? What line is it on? It's good that you posted the error, but you need to post all errors (if that's not the only one) plus the exact text of the error, not just the error (i.e. include file and line info).

Comment: @Seth It is on lines 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, and 70 in the main header. Basically everywhere that something with type CopyRow is declared.

Comment: are there any other errors you get? Look carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are can't include CPAMountMain.h in CopyRow.h and CopyRow.h in CPAMountMain.h! You have to decide the order in wich you want to include the files.

Since CPAMountMain.h only use *pointers* to CopyRow class, you can use a forward declaration instead of including CopyRow.h:

```
// CPAMountMain.h
class CopyRow;
```

and remove the `#include "CopyRow.h"` in CPAMountMain.h, this should work.

Comment: Or remove the `include CPAmountMain.h` from CopyRow.h

Comment: Or make sure to always include `CopyRow.h` first, but that's a bad solution. +1

Comment: @Mat Yes, it is actually much better!

Comment: This worked, but only by removing the include in CopyRow. When I used a forward declaration as stated by you, I got all sorts of errors around the constructor of CopyRow when actually instantiating the variable. I'm very new to C++ and am building this project to learn more about it, however this is something I don't understand. Thank you very much, though.

Comment: @Matt if you use a forward declaration, you have to include the CopyRow header in the `CPAmountMain.cpp` file.